# Check if algorithm for cities in radius is working right

Tags: algorithm, latitude-longitude

I have that algorithm that checks for a cities around a city I choose within 50 km. It uses latitude and longitude, but I don't know if it checks right the cities, because I have a database with a lot of cities from Australia and their lat and long and I don't know if my code is working the right way. I'm doing a lot of testing, but it is slow and I can't tell if it's accurate enough.

So I'm asking: Is there any way to check that let's say Sidney in Australia with postal code 2000 has let's say 50 cities in radius of 50 km as neighbors. Any website or something? Anything?

Comment: This article should give you a variety of possibilities, including code snippets and algorithms. http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Many databases nowadays have specialised functions/operators for handling geometric queries like this.

Comment: How about telling us how your algorithms works? I assume it's a bit more complicated that `a^2+b^2=c^2`, maybe taking curvature of earth into account, i.e. in non-euclidian geometry?

Comment: I second tobias_k - please provide some details about your specific algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to check:

Asuming your algorithm checks the cities by a distance calculation.

Like

```
if (distance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) < radius) {
  // isInside..
}
```

Then you just have to test that your distance calcualtion method works.

Possibilities:
Test cases:
1) distance between two lat lon points: take from google earth, and compare with their value, or use a web service to calculate the distance between the two points

2) Test overlapping datum limit (longitude -180/180): one point west of limit: longitude1 -179.0, the other east: longitude = 0.0001 (should give about 111.0km) for both having latitude = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Generate artificial data sets with known patterns. For example

- a city with postal code 2000 and 50 cities within 50 km and another 50 right outside the 50 km radius.
- create 20 cities in a line, all with 1 km distance to their direct neighbors. You can put that line in latitudinal and longitudinal direction, maybe even inclined
- a grid of cities so you can calculate the number of cities